# Why is the Twitter Bootstrap dropdown not toggling, neither is the brand toggle

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am playing around with trying to get a nav bar. I haven't even customized the code directly from here [Components - Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Nav Bar</title>
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="templates/template100/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="templates/template100/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">


</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

That is the entirety of my html. the code in the body tags is directly copy and pasted from the linked webpage above. In that webpage the toggle works on the dropdown but does not when I load my html file which you can find here [test.html](http://www.mariahswind.com/TNGSandBox/test.html). Why is this not working for me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include [jquery](http://jquery.com/) if you plan on using bootstrap.js.

Comment: Thank you. Now I've added '<script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>' but it's still not working.

Comment: I thought maybe I had my script tags in the wrong place. So I moved them to the bottom of the body and it's still not working.

Comment: I've managed to get the dropdown working here [http://www.mariahswind.com/TNGSandBox/test2.html] but I've yet to isolate the element that is making the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include jQuery, which is required.